# How tor retrieve String array from JSON Array?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, serializable

I have an Android App (written in Java) which retrieves a JSON object from the backend, parses it, and displays the data in the app. Everything is working fine (meaning that every field is being displayed correctly) except for one field. All the fields being displayed correctly are `String` whereas the one field which is causing the error is a string array!

Sample Object being retried from backend:

```
{
        "attendance_type": "2",
        "guest": [
            "Test Guest",
            "Test Guest 2"
        ],
        "member_id": "1770428",
        "attendance_time": "2020-04-27 04:42:22",
        "name": "HENRY  HHH",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "henry@mailinator.com",
        "onesignal_playerid": "",
        "user_image": "311591.png",
        "dateOfBirth": "06/22/1997",
        "employeeID": "543210",
        "socialSecurityNumber": "0000"
    }
```

As I said, all the fields are being retrieved correctly except the "guest field"

This is the class in which everything is Serialized:

```
package com.lu.scanner.ui.attendance.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class AttendanceDetails {

    String date;
    @SerializedName("attendance_type")
    private String attendance_type;
    @SerializedName("member_id")
    private String member_id;
    @SerializedName("attendance_date")
    private String attendance_date;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("onesignal_playerid")
    private String onesignal_playerid;
    @SerializedName("user_image")
    private String user_image;
    @SerializedName("dateOfBirth")
    private String dateOfBirth;
    @SerializedName("employeeID")
    private String employeeID;
    @SerializedName("socialSecurityNumber")
    private String socialSecurityNumber;
    @SerializedName("attendance_time")
    private String attendance_time;
    @SerializedName("guest")
    private String[] guest;

    public AttendanceDetails(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAttendance_type() {
        return attendance_type;
    }

    public void setAttendance_type(String attendance_type) {
        this.attendance_type = attendance_type;
    }

    public String getMember_id() {
        return member_id;
    }

    public void setMember_id(String member_id) {
        this.member_id = member_id;
    }

    public String getAttendance_date() {
        return attendance_date;
    }

    public void setAttendance_date(String attendance_date) {
        this.attendance_date = attendance_date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getOnesignal_playerid() {
        return onesignal_playerid;
    }

    public void setOnesignal_playerid(String onesignal_playerid) {
        this.onesignal_playerid = onesignal_playerid;
    }

    public String getUser_image() {
        return user_image;
    }

    public void setUser_image(String user_image) {
        this.user_image = user_image;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(String employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public String getAttendance_time() {
        return attendance_time;
    }

    public void setAttendance_time(String attendance_time) {
        this.attendance_time = attendance_time;
    }

    public String[] getGuest(){
        return guest;
    }

    public void setGuest(String[] guest){
        this.guest=guest;
    }
}
```

This is the SQLLite database:

```
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDANCE_DETAILS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDANCE_DETAILS +
        "( date TEXT , " +
        "attendance_type TEXT, " +
        "member_id TEXT, " +
        "attendance_date TEXT, " +
        "name TEXT, " +
        "email TEXT, " +
        "onesignal_playerid TEXT, " +
        "user_image TEXT, " +
        "dateOfBirth TEXT, " +
        "employeeID TEXT, " +
        "socialSecurityNumber TEXT, " +
        "attendance_time TEXT, " +
        "guest TEXT); ";
```

And finally, there is where the data is being retrieved:

```
public List<AttendanceDetails> getAllAttendanceDetails() {
    List<AttendanceDetails> attendanceDetailsList = new ArrayList<AttendanceDetails>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ATTENDANCE_DETAILS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AttendanceDetails attendanceDetails = new AttendanceDetails();
            attendanceDetails.setDate(cursor.getString(0));
            attendanceDetails.setAttendance_type(cursor.getString(1));
            attendanceDetails.setMember_id(cursor.getString(2));
            attendanceDetails.setAttendance_date(cursor.getString(3));
            attendanceDetails.setName(cursor.getString(4));
            attendanceDetails.setEmail(cursor.getString(5));
            attendanceDetails.setOnesignal_playerid(cursor.getString(6));
            attendanceDetails.setUser_image(cursor.getString(7));
            attendanceDetails.setDateOfBirth(cursor.getString(8));
            attendanceDetails.setEmployeeID(cursor.getString(9));
            attendanceDetails.setSocialSecurityNumber(cursor.getString(10));
            attendanceDetails.setAttendance_time(cursor.getString(11));
            attendanceDetails.setGuest(cursor.getString(12));
            
            attendanceDetailsList.add(attendanceDetails);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return attendanceDetailsList;
}
```

Therefore, the main problem, I think, is that the TEXT type in the table creation is not compatible with the String array. Plus I think the `cursor.String()` function is not working for the `"guest"` string array properly. What can I do to make all of this code compatible with the `"guest"` field?

NOTE: Everything is working perfectly fine except for the guest field...

Comment: try replace String[] with List<String> in field guest

Answer (score 0):

A Database stores rows of data, divided into columns. Each column is a skalar. SQLite only supports (basically) numbers and Text for columns. A List of Texts (or array from strings) doesn't fit in there. You are trying to assign a single String to an array.

You have two options:

1. Model guest as its own table and use foreign keys and the appropriate JOIN to fetch the data.
2. Encode the data yourself. If you don't want to query the array, but always retrieve the whole thing, this is the easier way:

   ```
   Gson gson;
   String guestSerialized = gson.toJson(attendanceDetails.getGuest);
   // Insert data like this

   // Retrieve:
   attendanceDetails.setGuest(gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(12), String[].class))
   ```

That is, if you are using GSON for JSON (de)serialization. You can choose a different format or library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give some name in the fields of "guest", something like:

```java
"guest": [
   {
    "guest" : "Test Guest",
   },
   {
    "guest" : "Test Guest 2"
    },
],
```

Then, in order to read these values, you can do that:

```java
JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("guest"); 
Map address = ((Map)jo.get("guest"))

Iterator itr = ja.iterator();
Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1;
          
while (itr.hasNext()) {
   itr1 = ((Map) itr.next()).entrySet().iterator(); 
   while (itr1.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue()); 
   } 
}
```

Where: 
**pair.getKey** is the name of the key ("guest") 
**pair.getValue** is the value of the key ("Test Guest")

The source code is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/).

Sorry if I have made any mistakes. Please ask for clarifications! :)